# the 'linkedlist.head' is assigned but is never used

Tags: c#, linked-list, warnings, singly-linked-list

I´m building a new simply linked list from an example but I get a weird warning from the `head` node from the start. The warning does not show up on the example but shows in mine.

How worried should I be and is there a way to fix it?

The exact error I get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Warning    CS0414 The field
>   'LinkedList.head' is assigned but its value is never
>   used  myLinkedList

```
public class Node
{
    private object data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(object data, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get { return this.data; }
        set {  this.data = value; }
    }


    public Node Next
    {
        get { return this.next; }
        set { this.next = value; }
    }
}
```

I have method in the class but the warning was the from the start

```
public class Node
{
    private object data;
    private Node next;
}
```

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. It's telling you that you have an unused variable.

Comment: I think you must be missing something in your code.  I do not see a `head` field. In any case, it is a rather benign *warning* that just tells you that you have a redundant field.

Comment: Capitalization is no bad thing. You however get that warning because you have declared a variable that you don´t use in any way, neither by setting its value nor by reading it. Simply delete that variable and everything is fine.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

The *Warning* is not in yout *Node* class, rather in your *LinkedList* class.

You have a *head* field which probably doesn't have any *getter/setter* and none of your methods using it.

Probably you asign value in your *LinkedList* constructor, but later on never use the *head* field.

Comment: thanks it was because i didn't have getter and setter. thanks for the tip.